# Value Displays when Running Stored Procedure in SSMS but not in SSRS

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that uses table variables to create a query and runs perfectly when executing in SQL Server Management Studio.  However, the column referring to this table variable does not display when running the stored procedure in Query Designer.

I have used this method on many other reports without issue, but cannot figure out why the value will display in SSMS and not in SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh nights sleep, I realized it was how a parameter was being passed to the Sub Stored Procedures.  The main stored procedure had a where clause that contained a "LIKE @Parameter" but the Sub Stored Procedure contained an "= @Parameter", so when a "%" was passed into the parameter the main Stored Procedure returned results, but nothing was displayed from the Sub Stored Procedure.

Simply just a case of making my job harder on myself...